# How to add text qualifier (") while exporting data using SQLCMD command?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am exporting data from SQL Server table to CSV using SQLCMD:

```
sqlcmd -S serverdetails -s"^" -d dbname -U username -P password -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT on; Select  * from table with (nolock) " > c:\\USERS\\a\\b\\export_file.csv -s"^" -W """;
```

I am getting data like this:

```
id^column1^column2^column3^column4
1^abc^cde^www.google.com^8776565
2^abc^cde^www.google.com^8776565
3^abc^cde^www.google.com^8776565
```

I want output like this:

```
"id"^"column1"^"column2"^"column3"^"column4"
"1"^"abc"^"cde"^"www.google.com"^"8776565"
"2"^"abc"^"cde"^"www.google.com"^"8776565"
"3"^"abc"^"cde"^"www.google.com"^"8776565"
```

Please suggest how I can do this with `select * from table`. I don't want to specify all columns and concatenate `"` with them.

Answer (score 0):

The double quote character has to be escaped with a backslash,
try to add `"\"^\""`;

```
sqlcmd -S serverdetails -s"\"^\"" -d dbname -U username -P password -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT on; Select  * from table with (nolock) " > c:\\USERS\\a\\b\\export_file.csv -s"\"^\"" -W """
```

Comment: It gives output like this

`id"column1"column2"column3"column4
1"abc"asasa"21212"233334`